# Syscall Constant syscall.ENONET Undefined in Go

Tags: macos, go, system-calls

I tried to run the following bar.go script

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", uintptr(syscall.ENONET))
}
```

by calling `go run bar.go` and get this error:

```
# command-line-arguments
./bar.go:9:29: undefined: syscall.ENONET
```

I am using Mac and go version `1.14.3 darwin/amd64`. I tried to run this exact script on Go playground, https://play.golang.org/p/ecMZPsGgGOa and it worked.

I tried to run the script using `CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64` and got this error instead:

```
fork/exec /var/folders/2l/dj6ph5t92y17vhtv3n6xzr5r0000gn/T/go-build847134732/b001/exe/bar: exec format error
```

How do I get `syscall.ENONET` to work on Mac?

Thank you

Comment: Your mac is not ARM.

Comment: Okay, tried amd64, but ran into the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there's some weird problem with it. Although, [syscall](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/) is locked down now.

```
Deprecated: this package is locked down. 
Callers should use the corresponding package in the golang.org/x/sys repository instead.
```

I tried out with `go version go1.14.3 darwin/amd64`, but I got the same problem.

But in the documentation, we have:

```golang
ENONET          = Errno(0x40)
```

As, [Errno](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Errno) is also exported type you can explicitly mock the same behaviour:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", syscall.Errno(0x40)) // 64
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", syscall.Errno(0x40)) // host is down
}
```

Comment: And no need to enable CGO: `CGO_ENABLED=1`